# strange dataclass decorator behaviour with fields

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I recently ran into strange behavior related to dataclasses in python. When using fields with `default_factory`, repeated call of the decorator results in an error.

As for me, this looks like a bug, because the field does not work out as a full-fledged default value. Accordingly, I would like to ask a question. what is the reason for this behavior of dataclasses?

source:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 5
    b: int = 6
    
B = dataclass(A)
print(B == A)
```

output:

```
True
```

on the other hand

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 5
    b: List = field(default_factory=lambda: [1, 2, 3])
    
B = dataclass(A)
print(B == A)
```

output:

```
TypeError: non-default argument 'b' follows default argument
```

and finally if you change order of `a` and `b` in last snippet you'll obtain `True` in the output.

Comment: i'm using python3.8

Comment: but why do you want to apply the decorator more then once?

Comment: normally for subclassing you'd do something like `@dataclass class B(A): pass`, which thankfully does work.

Comment: I am writing a utility for working with fairly specific configs, which slightly complements the work of dataclasses in order to increase readability. One of the utility decorators takes a class as input, performs some manipulations with it, and then wraps it in a dataclass. Due to the peculiarity described in this question, if I do not add some checks to my utility, its users run the risk of getting poorly interpreted errors if they feed not a class, but a dataclass inside this decorator

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I guess one way to handle that would be to check if the class passed in is a dataclass. Then if you still want to wrap it with decorator again, you’ll need to loop through `fields` and find all fields that have a default factory, then handle those cases separately.

Comment: No, it's not a bug. There's no reason to expect that you should be able to apply the @dataclass decorator twice. Also note, a "dataclass" isn't a type.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

```
TypeError: non-default argument 'b' follows default argument
```

is pretty clear, you can't put a fields without defaults following fields with them. Specifying a `default_factory` for a field is not the same as giving it a default value.

Luckily in this particular case there's an easy workaround, just define a `default_factory` for the `a` field too, so `b` no longer follows one with a default argument. I certainly don't understand all the details of the current `dataclass` implementation, so can't really say whether it's a bug or not — the comments in the code basically just echo what the error says.

That said, generally speaking default argument values shouldn't be mutable objects, and that's the primary use-case for using `default_factory` functions, so it's fairly obvious that initializing mutable fields types would need to be handled in a different manner than those with immutable ones, don't you think?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = field(default_factory=lambda: 5)
    b: List = field(default_factory=lambda: [1, 2, 3])

B = dataclass(A)
print(B == A)  # -> True
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I suppose it comes down to the fact that `a: int = 5` is using a class variable to provide the default value, whereas `b: List = field(default_factory=lambda: [1, 2, 3])` is doing (*waves hand at the mass of code in the `dataclasses` module*) something complicated so that there is actually a default value in the signature of the `__init__` method itself.

Comment: I agree with the content of this answer, but it's important to note it was actually right as it is in the question. Integers and strings are not mutable types in Python, so using a `default_factory` for them doesn't make much sense.  Also based on the comments, the OP mentioned they had no control over how dataclasses are defined (since other users create them), so it wouldn't be right to overwrite a default argument and replace it with a default factory, at least imo.

Comment: @rv.kvetch: No, it's not right in the question, hence the error (which I don't think is a bug). Plus I already indicated in my answer that while using a `default_factory` isn't necessary for `a` since it's immutable, that using one is merely a workaround. However I would agree (obviously) that any workaround that involves changing the base class is worthless if the OP can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

I was fooling around with this for a while, and came up with a pretty striaghtforward solution that looks like can work. As mentioned, this is **no** bug with `dataclasses`, because there's nothing that says it needs to support decorating the same class twice. Therefore I'm not entirely sure about what the issue is, however if for whatever reason we need to ensure a dataclass can support being decorated with the `@dataclass` decorator again, we need to ensure we unset all other values for a `field` that has a *default_factory* - other than the *default_factory* itself.

The below example demonstrates this pretty clearly:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields, MISSING
from typing import List


@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 5
    b: List = field(default_factory=lambda: [1, 2, 3])


print('== A Fields')
for f in fields(A):
    print(f)
    if f.default_factory is not MISSING:
        setattr(A, f.name, field(default_factory=f.default_factory))


B = dataclass(A)
print(B == A)
print()

print('== B Fields')
for f in fields(B):
    print(f)
```

Of course in your code, you can encapsulate the logic under `print('== A Fields')` into a helper function, and change `A` instead to a generic `cls` argument that gets passed in to a function. This would allow you to modify any dataclass fields that are set with a *default_factory*, so that no error is raised when the data class is re-decorated again.